# Can't isolate desired results out of crude ones

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get the name of neighbors from a webpage. I've used `requests` library along with `re` module to parse the content from some script tag out of that site. when I run the script I get the name of neighbors in the right way. However, the problem is i've used this line ***`if not item.startswith("NY:"):continue`*** to get rid of unwanted results from that page. I do not wish to use this hardcoded portion `NY:` to do this trick.

> - [website link](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start=1)

I've tried with:

```
import re
import json
import requests

link = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start=1'

resp = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
data = json.loads(re.findall(r'data-hypernova-key[^{]+(.*)--></script>',resp.text)[0])
items = data['searchPageProps']['filterPanelProps']['filterInfoMap']
for item in items:
    if not item.startswith("NY:"):continue
    print(item)
```

Result I'm getting (desired result):

```
NY:New_York:Brooklyn:Mill_Basin
NY:New_York:Bronx:Edenwald
NY:New_York:Staten_Island:Stapleton
```

If I do not use this line ***`if not item.startswith("NY:"):continue`***, the results are something like:

```
rating
NY:New_York:Brooklyn:Mill_Basin
NY:New_York:Bronx:Edenwald
NY:New_York:Staten_Island:Stapleton
NY:New_York:Staten_Island:Lighthouse_Hill
NY:New_York:Queens:Rochdale
NY:New_York:Queens:Pomonok
BusinessParking.validated
food_court
NY:New_York:Queens:Little_Neck
```

The bottom line is I wish to get everything started with `NY:New_York:`. What I meant by unwanted results are `rating`, `BusinessParking.validated`, `food_court` and so on.

***How can I get the neighbors without using any hardcoded portion of search within the script?***

Comment: So  you want `NY:New_York:Bronx:Edenwald` but not `NY:New_York:Staten_Island:Lighthouse_Hill`?

Comment: I want everything started with `NY:New_York:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what your complete data set looks like, but based on your sample,
you might use something like:

```
if ':' not in item:
    continue

# or perhaps:
if item.count(':') < 3:
    continue

# I'd prefer a list comprehension if I didn't need the other data 
items = [x for x in data['searchPageProps']['filterPanelProps']['filterInfoMap'] if ':' in x]
```

If that doesn't work for what you're trying to achieve then you could just use a variable for the state.

Comment: When I comply with your suggestion, I get this type of results `g:-73.997490406,40.7030089925,-73.9910960197,40.7078889327` as well.

Comment: The second option above would not produce a result with less than 3 ':' in it.

Comment: Yes, your second solution dd the trick @Amir Almusawi. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution - using BeautifulSoup - which doesn't involve regex or hardcoding "NY:New_York" is below; it's convoluted, but mainly because Yelp buried it's treasure several layers deep...

So for future reference:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests

link = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start=1'

resp = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

target = soup.find_all('script')[14]
content = target.text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
js_data = json.loads(content)
```

And now the fun of extracting NYC info from the json begins....

```
for a in js_data:
  if a == 'searchPageProps':
    level1 = js_data[a]
    for b in  level1:
        if b == 'filterPanelProps':
            level2 = level1[b]
            for c in level2:                    
                if c == 'filterSets':
                    level3 = level2[c][1]
                    for d in level3:
                        if d == 'moreFilters':
                            level4 = level3[d]
                            for e in range(len(level4)):   
                                print(level4[e]['title'])
                                print(level4[e]['sectionFilters'])
                                print('---------------')
```

The output is the name of each borough plus a list of all neighborhoods in that borough. For example:

> Manhattan
>
> ['NY:New_York:Manhattan:Alphabet_City',
> 'NY:New_York:Manhattan:Battery_Park',
> 'NY:New_York:Manhattan:Central_Park', 'NY:New_York:Manhattan:Chelsea',
> '...]

etc.